# How to optimize CSS code?

Tags: optimization, css

How should I go about optimizing CSS code? There's various CSS3 lines, like -moz- and -webkit-, border-top-left-radius, etc.. I believe bigger CSS files increase page load time significantly.

And another question: I've written quite some code, however some of it is left unused. I have over 2000 lines of CSS code, and I bet around 200-300 lines could be removed, perhaps even more. Is it worth revising all the code? It would take quite some time...

Comment: Chrome's dev tools can show you which CSS rules are not used...

Comment: Revising your code is not a bad idea.

Comment: If you make sure that the CSS files are cached (in the browser), it shouldn't be an issue regardless how big the CSS files are...

Comment: That is a good point, I do use a caching script. Although, the loading time would be longer for first-time visitors. First impression is the most important one, isn't it?

Comment: @Jack It's the content that counts. I regularly visit a bunch of sites that are really slow, but I still visit them because I like their content. `:)` (e.g. Zelda Informer, Replay Hub on Game Informer)

Comment: Good point as well. :) I will check out the techniques mentioned below though, but I don't think I'll bother spending half a day revising my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GZip the files](http://www.wangarific.com/how-to-gzip-css-files/) before uploading them on server

It will reduce the files size significantly

**Edit: Effect of GZipping -**

By gzipping the .css file on Bargaineering, its size dropped from 28.2K to 7.3K, a 74.1% savings.

Answer (score 2):

- always remove the last semicolon:

  `body { background: black; color: white; }`
   to
  `body { background: black; color: white }`
- combine multiple properties:

  `.class { margin-top: 10px; margin-right : 20px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: 40px; }`
  to
  `.class { margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; }`
- use simple colors (instead of `` `#FFFFFF, #AABBCC, #FF0000 `` put `#FFF, #ABC, #F00`)
- the most important thing: [**minify your code**](http://minifycss.com/) before uploading on the server. It will remove whitespaces and comments and significantly reduce your code and file size.

Comment: `margin:10` won't work (it only works with `0`). Also, removing the last semi-colon is overkill.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Removed that.
I've seen many suggestions about removing the last semi-colon, and I've never seen that someone said it's bad. However, I prefer to put semi-colon always. It's a habit + it's easier to add code later.

Comment: Your left and right margin values are backwards, should be 10px 40px 30px 20px in the shortened example.

Answer (score 0):

The smaller the file, the quicker it will download and the faster users can render the styles. There are various minifying scripts, I'd check out the YUI Compressor: http://refresh-sf.com/yui/